# windows will not boot from GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10, bootloader

I was goofing around with ms-config and changed to "normal boot". Ought not done that! Now when I select Windows 10 from the dual boot GRUB menu it says "No Boot loader" or some sorts. Tried to repair from CD via command prompt with bootrec /rebuild, bootrec /fixmbr, bootrec /fixboot. Of course, this didn't work, I assume because the system is an UEFI. So, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You didn't even mention an on-topic OS/release, you mentioned only Windows 10, and used windows commands. GRUB is used by many systems, and most are not on-topic here, https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Have you tried something like: https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager-software/fix-uefi-boot-in-windows-10-8-7.html

Comment: guiverc, sorry for the trigger. I just figured since I was on ASK UBUNTU you'd know the other OS used for GRUB was Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

You can use Boot Repair. It will regenerate your GRUB and boot installation for both Ubuntu and Windows 10.

1- You can install and run it from Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt install --assume-yes boot-repair
boot-repair
```

2- Or you can create a live USB: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and things just got worse. Ended up I a GRUB2 minimal CLI that was a never ending loop. But that's OK. It just gave me a reason to do a Clean install which I've been think about for a few weeks now. Anyway, have a great day. And, my apologies to the board monitor for assuming people could fill in the blanks and figure I was not working on a windows phone.